# Модификация DOM дерева

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Суть задачи такая, посреди страницы будет `div` блок, в котором c абсолютным позиционированием должны появляться кнопочки. Такая проблема, не могу поместить генерируемые DOM элементы в этот самый div блок.  Надо чтобы генерируемые скриптом элементы помещались в `<div id="menu222"></div>`

html

```
  <input type="button" onclick="NewTeg()" value="Добавить кнопку">
 <div id="menu222">


</div>
```

JS

```
function NewTeg() {

var d=document.createElement('div');
NUM = (!self.NUM) ? 1 : ++NUM;

d.style.textAlign = "center";
d.style.padding = "8px";
d.style.color = "#fff";
d.style.borderRadius ='5px';
d.style.background='#6492cb';
d.style.position='absolute';
d.id ="Dialog" + NUM;
d.className = ('drag');
d.innerHTML = NUM;
document.body.appendChild(d);


}
```

Comment: Я не совсем понял, у вас получается добавить элементы, но не получается конкретно в див menu222 ?

Comment: я учусь, и появился такой вопрос

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы добавляете в `body` вот этой строчкой:
`document.body.appendChild(d);`, а нужно выбрать ваш `div`
`var box = document.getElementById('menu222')`, а уже для него добавлять ваши элементы
`box.appendChild(d);`